# Laravel 5.3: Missing argument 2

Tags: php, laravel, routes, view, controllers

Having a problem with redirection.

Example, in this view,

[image: here]

we have the show view for notes of a company named Tiago.

The link that says 'Create Note for Tiago', looks like the following:

```
<p><a href="{{route('company.companies.notes.create', $company->companyID)}}">Create Note for {{$company->Company_Name}}</a></p>
```

where $company->companyID is being grabbend from the controller, which looks like this:

```
public function create(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $company = $request->user()->company()->first();
    $notes = NotesCompany::where('companyID', "=", $id)->get();

    return view("company.companies.notes.create", compact('company', 'notes'));

}
```

and has the following route:

```
GET|HEAD  | company/companies/notes/create | company.companies.notes.create | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyNotesController@create | web,company   |

Route::resource('company/companies/notes', 'CompanyNotesController',['names'=>[


    'index'=>'company.companies.notes.index',
    'create'=>'company.companies.notes.create',
    'store'=>'company.companies.notes.store',
    'edit'=>'company.companies.notes.edit',
    'show'=>'company.companies.notes.show'

]]);
```

The problem is, when pressin in 'Create Notes for Tiago', the following error comes through:

[image: here]

**Any debug here? Appreciated**

Tiago

Comment: Remove Request $request and check.

Comment: that didn't solve the problem...

Comment: when you have a request, that should come from a form submission and more over you are using the default routes please check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers

Comment: What was the error you got from Jagadesha NH suggestion?

Comment: To remove the request used then:
 $company = Company::first();

now, the problem that shows up, is 'Missing argument 1'

and the domain looks like this:

'...public/company/companies/notes/create?1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the `create` resource method does not take any url parameters. It can does, however, when attempting to use nested resources. It looks like you are attempting to use nested resource routes, but have not set it up properly.

Your route needs to look like:

```
Route::resource('companies.notes', 'CompanyNotesController',['names'=>[
    'index'=>'company.companies.notes.index',
    'create'=>'company.companies.notes.create',
    'store'=>'company.companies.notes.store',
    'edit'=>'company.companies.notes.edit',
    'show'=>'company.companies.notes.show'
]]);
```

This will create urls that look like `companies/{company_id}/notes/create`, etc., and that `company_id` will be passed into your `create` method.

I do not believe there is a way to modify the generated routes when using nested resources. You could attempt `Route::resource('company/companies.notes', ...`, but I don't know if that will work.